# Watch content of stl vector via gdb

Tags: c++, stl, gdb

I've got a stl vector of custom class objects defined in a global namespace (yeah, evil, I know).
Now I would like to set a watchpoint in gdb to monitor possible changes in a (public) member variable for a certain element of this vector. Something like:

```
watch custom_namespace::vec[123].aVariable
```

If I do this, then gdb (Version 7.1 on Ubuntu Lucid) segfaults.
Are there alternative ways. Is this possible at all?

Comment: What's the type of that variable?

Comment: Regardless of your syntax, this shouldn't lead to a segfault. Have you reported this behavior to the gdb mailing-list ? They might both help you and fix the bug.

Comment: The variable itself is of type double. The vector holds objects of a class that mainly bundles some double, int and bool values. Nothing fancy there.
No, I haven't checked with the gdb-list yet. Actually I use ddd, I would have to check with standalone gdb first..

Answer (score 2):

See if this applies to your case (from [gdb manual](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html)):

> `Sometimes, gdb cannot set a hardware watchpoint because the data type of the watched expression is wider than what a hardware watchpoint on the target machine can handle. For example, some systems can only watch regions that are up to 4 bytes wide; on such systems you cannot set hardware watchpoints for an expression that yields a double-precision floating-point number (which is typically 8 bytes wide). As a work-around, it might be possible to break the large region into a series of smaller ones and watch them with separate watchpoints.`

Try casting the address to `(int*)`. Does it still segfault?

Also STL `vector` will move its content if it needs to extend the internal buffer, so your object might just be "stolen" from under the watchpoint.